# C++ array of member function pointers?

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pointers, member

Been using the website for a long time and it's answered countless questions for me.  I've been programming for a long time, but I'm new to C++.  This is my first question here.

I need to have an array that holds member function pointers.  The functions that the array will be pointing to have the same arguments and return type, but are members of DIFFERENT classes.  Is it possible to store pointers to member functions of different classes in the same array?

Comment: It's possible if you store them as `std::function<Ret(ArgsWithoutObjectType)>` and use `std::bind` to bind objects to them when inserting them.

Comment: Are the classes related by inheritance?

Comment: @BenVoigt: even if they are, it doesn't really help: you can't convert a pointer-to-member for a derived class to a pointer-to-member to a base type. It can only work the other way (they are contra variant). Of course, if the classes are in an inheritance chain and having pointer-to-members to the most derived in the array, that would work.

Comment: Actually, what do you try to achieve? This sounds somewhat like an [XY-Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @Dietmar Kühl: You cannot implicitly convert in that direction. However, the language purposely supports `static_cast` conversions in that direction specifically for that reason.

Comment: @DietmarKuhl: It doesn't handle every conceivable scenario, but a pointer-to-virtual-member definitely does work with functions with "are members of different classes", and generally virtual functions are the way you want to have behavior that varies by type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you what to literally store pointers of *pointer-to-member* type in your array, the answer is: it depends. It depends on whether there is a hierarchical relationship between your classes.

If your classes are completely unrelated, then you can only `reinterpret_cast` your pointers to some common type, like `void (SomeArbitraryClass::*)()` and then `reinterpret_cast` them back to their original types when performing the call. This is basically a "no" answer, since this is little more than a rather ugly hack.

(Alternatively, as Dietmar Kühl suggested, you can use type-erasure techniques, like the one offered by `std::function<>` in C++11 to store callable objects in your array. Such objects will not be pointers-to-member anymore though.)

But if your classes are members of the same class hierarchy, then you can rely on the fact that in C++ class member pointers are *contravariant*. This means that pointer to member of base class can be implicitly converted to pointer to member of derived class. And even though they don't convert implicitly in the reverse direction, the language supports this conversion through `static_cast`. So, you have to give the array elements the type `R (CommonBaseClass::*)(Args)` and use `static_cast` to that type when filling in the array. In this case you don't have to convert these pointers back to original type when performing the call - the language will do everything correctly by itself (assuming you supply objects of correct type at the moment of pointer dereference).

Comment: That may work in practice, but I think calling a function through a pointer with improper type is undefined behavior according to the standard.  The only thing you're allowed to do is to cast it back, and the even though that conversion is implicit, it won't be triggered here.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: No, this is a feature that required a noticeable amount of development before C++98 was finalized (it was not in the last draft, but made it into the final C++98). The language allows dereferencing such pointers *without* casting them back assuming the *dynamic* type of the object used for the call contains the member pointed by the pointer. (Otherwise, the behavior is undefined.) (See 5.5/4 in C++98)

Comment: The last draft of C++98 prohibited such `static_cast` and had no such language in 5.5/4. The final C++98 had these areas changed specifically to allow this `static_cast` for pointers-to-member, and to express the validity of dereference of such pointers in 5.5 in terms of *dynamic type* of the object. This change was made specifically to introduce this [obscure] feature into the language.

Comment: Actually, the large portion of the reason pointers to member functions are "heavy" (contain some extra household information inside) is to support this functionality, i.e. to allow calling `(base_ptr->*derived_member)()` when `derived_member` points to a function that is not present in base class.

Comment: Well my classes aren't related at all.  I figured the answer was no, but I wanted to make sure.  I can just move the functions outside of the classes.  It looks ugly, but it'll work.  Thanks for the info!

Comment: @user: A nicer way of doing that could be static member functions -- pointers to them are ordinary function pointers and not pointer-to-member types.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider the object of the class an additional argument into the member function (basically, what becomes the `this` pointer). Since the member functions, thus, all get different argument types, you can't store them in an array directly. You could, however, type-erase the class type using something like `std::function<RC(Args)>`. When you have members for different classes, you probably need to provide suitable objects which can be bound to the member functions using `std::bind()`.